# ASP.NET MVC4 entity validation errors: User name already taken

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am new to ASP.NET MVC4, getting a validation error on the code below.

My app is using Identity and a Database.

I have some tables populated with some testing data. A call to `dc.SaveChanges()` returns Validation errors.

I created the following classes: `Faculty` deriving from class `Person` deriving from class `IdentityUser`.

I created a role named `Faculty`, then created a `Faculty` object named `mark` and added it the `Faculty` role. As `mark` logs in and the Database starts initializing, I get the error `"User name Peter is already taken."`

An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

### Code

Class `Person`:

```
public class Faculty : Person {
    public Faculty() {
        this.Courses = new List<Course>();
        SenecaId = string.Empty;
    }
    public Faculty(string fname, string lname, string phone, string senId)
        : base(fname, lname, phone) {
        this.Courses = new List<Course>();
        this.Messages = new List<Message>();
        SenecaId = senId;
    }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0][0-9]{8}$", ErrorMessage = "0 followed by 8 digits")]
    public string SenecaId { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Class `IdentityUser`:

```
public class Person : IdentityUser {
    public Person() {
      FirstName = LastName = Phone = string.Empty;
    }
    public Person(string f, string l, string p) {
      FirstName = f;
      LastName = l;
      Phone = p;
    }
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(40, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[2-9]\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "nnn-nnn-nnnn")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Role `Faculty`:

```
string roleFaculty = "Faculty";
if (!RoleManager.RoleExists(roleFaculty)) {
    var roleFacultyCreateResult = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(roleFaculty));
}
```

Creating `Faculty` object (**Mark**) and adding it to role `Faculty`:

```
// 1 create faculty Mark (8)
Faculty mark = new Faculty();
// add "mark" to role "faculty"
mark.SenecaId = "034234678";
mark.FirstName = "Mark";
mark.LastName = "McTest";
mark.Phone = "555-567-6789";
mark.UserName = "Mark";

string UserMarkPw = "123456";
var UserMarkCreate = UserManager.Create(mark, UserMarkPw);
if (UserMarkCreate.Succeeded) {
    var addUserMarkToRoleFacultyResult = UserManager.AddToRole(mark.Id, roleFaculty);
}
mark.HomeTown = "Markham";
var UserMarkInfo = new MyUserInfo() { 
    FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "McTest" };
mark.MyUserInfo = UserMarkInfo;
mark.PersonId = 8;
dc.Faculties.Add(mark);
```

The error:

```
"Entity of type Faculty in state Added has the following validation errors:"
...
"User name Peter is already taken."
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already bound them. *That's* your problem. `IdentityUser` *is* the user account, since `Faculty` is a `Person` is a `IdentityUser`, `Faculty` is a `IdentityUser`. By creating the `Faculty` object, you created a user account as well.

In fact, unless you customized the entity configuration, Entity Framework did all this in the AspNetUsers table with a discriminator column. In other words, you don't have an actual Faculty table or a Persons table, but one AspNetUsers table with a column filled the name of the specific class type ("Faculty", "Person", etc.).

**UPDATE**

Identity only supports one user type. You specify what type that will be with the `IdentityDbContext<>` generic you inherit from in your application's context. In your case, you've set that to `Person` (i.e. `IndentityDbContext<Person>`). That means, `ApplicationUser` is not utilized at all. That's fine if that's what you want. Your "user" can be named whatever you like; it doesn't have to be `ApplicationUser`. Then, you've merely employed STI (single-table inheritance) to add a more specific "type" of user, which would be your `Faculty` class. Entity Framework does this by default for inheritance stuctures where a base class is an entity (mapped to a database table). Basically all the fields for `Faculty`, `Person` *and* `IdentityUser` are all mapped to the same database table, and a discriminator column is added to track the specific class type that Entity Framework should instantiate when that row is pulled from the database. STI is a common inheritance strategy for mapping object hierarchies to a relational database, and for the most part it works well, but you need to keep in mind that all fields on superclasses *must* be nullable. In other words, you cannot have a field on `Faculty` that is NOT NULL at the database level, or you'll get an error. You can, however, make the field required through your application, even though it is technically not required at the database level to insert a new row.

Comment: Thank you, Chris! May I ask you to look at my updated question? I Added section 7.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a CustomMembershipProvider in that case. It's a bit annoying to get into it, but in the end it is way more useful than the out-of-the-box SimpleMembership thing as it can perfectly fit your needs and your existing DB fields etc.

Comment: Membership providers are not compatible with Identity.

Comment: Dear Chris, thank you for your valuable input. I have updated my question, could you look at section 8?

Comment: I believe this is race condition caused by adding related items to a new entity when those items already exist on their own. That's a bit obtuse, but essentially, when you add the new main entity, it attaches it and also attempts to attach its related objects, those related objects are already attached, and you get the error. Try adding the main entity first (not necessary saving, just call `.Add(entity)`) before associating the related properties with it.

Comment: Chris Pratt, you are saying "By creating the Faculty object, you created a user account as well." Do you mean I **don't have to create** user Peter, since I already have faculty Peter?

Comment: Yes. `Faculty` is a subclass of `Person` which is a subclass of `IdentityUser`, so an instance of `Faculty` will create a user record when saved.

Comment: I have edited and shortened my question. I have removed the redundancy but the error is still there.

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting error "User name Mark is already taken."
Because user with UserName **'Mark'** is created and saved in DB with following statement.

```
var UserMarkCreate = UserManager.Create(mark, UserMarkPw);
```

Again you are trying to add **'Mark'** in `dc` with statement `dc.Faculties.Add(mark)`;

Now when you do `dc.SaveChanges()`, it again tries to insert **'Mark'** in DB. Hence you are getting error,

> "User name Mark is already taken."