# Adding Many to Many relationship from ApplicationUser to custom entity

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to setup a many to many relationship in EF 6.1 from the User entity (ApplicationUser) in ASP.NET Identity to a custom entity (Group). I'm using Code First and Migrations with the stock standard MVC sample app with ASP.Net Identity. Running Update-Database seems to work nicely as I end up with all the AspNet* tables plus my entity and a linking table:

**Groups**
**GroupAspNetUsers**

My ApplicationUser declaration has a collection of Group, and likewise my Group has a collection of ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
```

I can create users and groups, but for the life of me I can't work out how to link them. I would have expected something like this to work:

```
Group group = Context.Groups.Single(g => g.Id == 1);
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // link this user to a group
    group.ApplicationUsers.Add(user);
    Context.SaveChanges();
```

However when I run the code above, I get a DbEntityValidationException stating the user name is already taken.

I've tried loading 2 custom entities and linking them in this way, which inserts a record into the linking table no problem.

So there is something I don't follow about how ApplicationUser is different.

My custom entities and the ASP.Net Identity entities should be using the same DB context as all my controllers inherit from a base controller.

**UPDATE:**
I've also tried approaching this from the other way around (add a group to a user), without any luck:

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // attempting to add group to a user
    user.Groups.Add(group);
    Context.SaveChanges();
```

This code runs without throwing an error, however it doesn't add a record to my GroupAspNetUsers table though.

My next step is to try creating a separate entity (eg. UserInfo) which has a 1 to 1 mapping with ApplicationUser. Then I should be able to setup a many to many from UserInfo to Group.

**SOLUTION**

The double insert problem stems from the UserManager.CreateAsync call, which will create the user on a different thread. The current thread, being unaware of this, then tries to insert the user again.

Changing the method to UserMannager.Create solved the problem, however as @Horizon_Net pointed out there are other issues with mixing identity and context methods (which I ran into).

The solution was to create the user, then redirect off to another controller to link the user to a group. This worked without a hitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not come from your groups collection. The following two lines are the problem

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
...
Context.SaveChanges();
```

What happens behind the scenes is that with the first call a user is created. With the second call it again tries to insert this user. That's the reason why you get this error message.

In general, you should avoid to mix the methods Identity gives you and working on the context itself. This can have a lot of side effects (like in your example).

For reference have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941693/asp-net-mvc4-entity-validation-errors-user-name-already-taken)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I can see the other issue is similar to mine, though ultimately I'm none the wiser about how to resolve it. I've updated my issue with a possible refactor that might help. Will update once I've tried it.

Comment: Actually, you were right. I didn't twig that in the first line UserManager.CreateAsync will go off and create the user on another thread, which is why it tries to insert the user twice.